# My Website is "overlaying" on the bigger screen

Tags: html, css

So i made a Watchlist which is actually just a picture gallery and a menu right now. but on the second, the bigger screen the pictures are overlaying my menu.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHh8T.jpg

well i think that its because i used px instead of % or smth like that so i tried changing it but the problem is finding out where. some of the tags dont even work with % for some reason. also im not even sure that thats the problem. thats just a guess from me.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
<title>HTML</title>
</head> 
<body>
 <div class="menu">
  <button class="untermenu">TV</button>
    <div class="untermenu-links">
    <a href="schauen.html">am schauen</a>
    <a href="fertig.html">geschaut</a>
    <a href="wird.html">wird geschaut</a>
    </div>
  <button class="untermenu">Anime</button>
    <div class="untermenu-links">
    <a href="schauen2.html">am schauen</a>
    <a href="fertig2.html">geschaut</a>
    <a href="wird2.html">wird geschaut</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
<img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/A121lm-WoYL._AC_UY218_.jpg" alt="Shadowhunters">      
  <div class="desc"><p>Staffel 2/3<br>Folge 20/20<br>am schauen</p></div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81b+18Wg5dL._AC_UY218_.jpg" alt="Brooklyn Nine Nine">
  <div class="desc"><p>Staffel 5/6<br>Folge 22/22<br>am schauen</p></div>
```

```
<script>
var untermenu = document.getElementsByClassName("untermenu");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < untermenu.length; i++) 
{
  untermenu[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
  {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var untermenuContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (untermenuContent.style.display === "block") 
    {
      untermenuContent.style.display = "none";
    } 
    else 
    {
      untermenuContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body
{
    background-color: #e2e2e0;
}

h1
{
 font-family: Arial, "Times new roman";
 position: relative;
 left: 170px;
}
.menu
{
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

 .menu a, .untermenu
 {
  padding: 8px 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
    }

div.gallery 
{
  position: relative;
  left: 9%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
    }

div.gallery:hover 
{
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
div.gallery img 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
}

div.desc 
{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

p
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.menu a:hover, .untermenu:hover
{
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.untermenu-links
{
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
}

.active 
{
  background-color: #093802;
  color: white;
}


#kleiner
{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

i expect it to look nice
it doesnt look nice.

Comment: try using a viewport

Comment: i added this code to meta: name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" but it doesnt do anything. isnt this for smaller screens?

Comment: And change the 100% of width to 100vw and of the height to 100vh

Comment: changed width to 100vw and height to 100vh. now it looks completly weird :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to post the whole HTML and CSS somewhere here or maybe on share a codepen, so that we can debug your code.

Also, I would suggest you to use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) for making layouts for your website. For example I can see that your design structure can we implemented using basic grid and flex . The implementation in your case would be basic and it would be a good start for you. Consider learning them.

> I have made changes in your code, added flex and grid. I have also implimented a responsiveness code, so that if the screen size reduces things still look good.

https://codepen.io/bhanusinghR/pen/LYPbazK?editors=1100

Code used:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
<title>HTML</title>
</head> 
<body>
  <div class="body-wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
  <button class="untermenu">TV</button>
    <div class="untermenu-links">
    <a href="schauen.html">am schauen</a>
    <a href="fertig.html">geschaut</a>
    <a href="wird.html">wird geschaut</a>
    </div>
  <button class="untermenu">Anime</button>
    <div class="untermenu-links">
    <a href="schauen2.html">am schauen</a>
    <a href="fertig2.html">geschaut</a>
    <a href="wird2.html">wird geschaut</a>
    </div>
</div>

  <div>
    <div class="gallery">
<img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/A121lm-WoYL._AC_UY218_.jpg" alt="Shadowhunters">      
  <div class="desc"><p>Staffel 2/3<br>Folge 20/20<br>am schauen</p></div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81b+18Wg5dL._AC_UY218_.jpg" alt="Brooklyn Nine Nine">
  <div class="desc"><p>Staffel 5/6<br>Folge 22/22<br>am schauen</p></div>


  </div>

  </div>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    background-color: #e2e2e0;
    padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

  .body-wrapper{
  display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 18% auto;
  grid-template-rows:auto;
}


h1
{
 font-family: Arial, "Times new roman";
 position: relative;
 left: 170px;
}
.menu
{
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
}

 .menu a, .untermenu
 {
  padding: 8px 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
    }

div.gallery 
{
  position: relative;
  left: 9%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
    }

div.gallery:hover 
{
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
div.gallery img 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
}

div.desc 
{
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

p
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.menu a:hover, .untermenu:hover
{
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.untermenu-links
{
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
}

.active 
{
  background-color: #093802;
  color: white;
}


#kleiner
{
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .body-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .menu {
    height:100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

I have created your layout using basic simple use of grid and flex.

Comment: tried it out but it doesnt work sadly. i will add the full code to the question

Comment: Yeah sure, it would be better.

Comment: Hey @DmitrijIvanov, I have changed my answer. Take a look. I have added couple of div in your HTML and made changes in your CSS. I have also added media query so that the webpage look better on mobile devices. Let me know if it solved your issue.!!

Comment: thanks it is working! but now the menu is so large how can i get it smaller/more to the left? i tried changing the padding from the menu and the untermenu i also tried margin 0 and changing width but it didnt do anything.

Comment: Just change this `grid-template-columns: 10% auto;`  "%" value is the percentage for width  of the menu. You can change it as you like it. Also, do look go through this(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) awesome guide if you want to learn about Grid layouting.

Comment: oh i would have thought this would be about the pictures.... but it works thx! now i just have to look into it and understand what you did. ill check out the link thx

Comment: actually, now that i added more pictures i have another problem. my menu ends between the 3rd and 4th picture. i can just change height to 100%, so it goes all the way down but instead i want the menu to stick to the screen. the problem is adding position fixed to .menu doesnt work and adding position fixed to .body-wrapper locks the scrollbar. i tried to fix it with z-index and overflow but i failed.

Comment: Hey @DmitrijIvanov, I have made changes to code according to your need. You need not use `position` for this, you have to use `overflow-y: scroll` to make that happen. Check it here : https://codepen.io/bhanusinghR/pen/LYPbazK
Also do consider giving this answer an upvote as well, so others can spot it. Thanks!!

Comment: awesome thank you! sadly i cant upvote since i need more reputation